# Which is the LaTeX font used by Google's DeepMind in this paper?

Tags: fonts, templates, two-column

I recently read this paper:

[Formal Algorithms for Transformers, Mary Phuong, Marcus Hutter](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.09238)

I have searched if there was any kind of template but I couldn't find any. The thing I am interested in the most is knowing which font they are using.

Comment: The source is available from https://arxiv.org/format/2207.09238 You can look it up there

Comment: That's XCharter

Comment: Thank you a lot to both of you!